# SQL Server query to find all routes from city A to city B with transfers

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I was asked this question while interviewing for developer position.

**Task**: Having flight routes stored in SQL Server table write query which will find all routes from city A to city B without transfer, with one or two transfers. For instance you have routes:

```
| From         | To
----------------------
Los Angeles     London   
Los Angeles     New York
New York        London
Los Angeles     Seattle
Seattle         Paris
Paris           London
```

And you need to find all routes with transfers from Los Angeles to London. The result should be like this

```
Route
------------------------
Los Angeles->London
Los Angeles->New York->London
Los Angeles->Seattle->Paris->London
```

My solution was this

```sql
select [From] + '->' + [To] as [Route] from Routes where [From] = 'Los Angeles' and [To] = 'London'
union 
select r1.[From] + '->' + r1.[To] + '->' + r2.[To] as [Route] from Routes as r1 
join Routes as r2 on r1.[To] = r2.[From]
where r1.[From] = 'Los Angeles' and r2.[To] = 'London'
union 
select r1.[From] + '->' + r1.[To] + '->' + r2.[To] + '->' + r3.[To] as [Route] from Routes as r1 
join Routes as r2 on r1.[To] = r2.[From]
join Routes as r3 on r2.[To] = r3.[From]
where r1.[From] = 'Los Angeles' and r3.[To] = 'London'
```

Works but looks not very good and if we need to find routes with 3, 4, 5 or more transfers we need to add new unions with more complex selects.

For this particular example it’s good because the people as a rule are not interested in flights with more than 2 transfers. But in general I think this query can look better. Perhaps someone can solve this task with more general query. Thanks.

Comment: In case you didn't know: if you add Seattle to LA as a route in your sample data you get an unexpected result: `LA->Seattle->LA->London`

Comment: Correct, so my interview solution was even with a bug. Solutions below work fine for this case too. Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right, you provided working general SQL solution for all RDBs. I see you had here one hint – SQL Server. It supports recursive CTE which can be used to solve this task.

```sql
with RoutesCTE as
(
    select CAST([From] + '->' + [To] as nvarchar(max)) as [Route]
          ,0 as TransfersCount
          ,[From]
          ,[To]
    from Routes

    union all

    select r.[Route] + '->' + r1.[To]
          ,TransfersCount + 1
          ,r.[From]
          ,r1.[To]
    from RoutesCTE r
        join Routes r1
            on r.[To] = r1.[From]
                and r1.[To] <> r.[From] 
                  and PATINDEX('%'+r1.[To]+'%', r.[Route]) = 0
)
select [Route]
from RoutesCTE 
where [From] = 'Los Angeles'
    and [To] = 'London'
    and TransfersCount <= 2
```

So, here you have general solution for SQL Server and you can filter them by transfers count.

Comment: Thank you Vasyl. Great, I really forgot about recursive CTE in MS SQL.

Comment: @VasylZvarydchuk That fix only works if the cycle is to the starting city. Try adding route `Paris -> Seattle`

Comment: Use `and PATINDEX('%'+r1.cTo+'%', r.[Route]) = 0` to avoid cycles problem.

Comment: Is it ok to add TransfersCount <=2 to the inner query after PATINDEX to improve the overall performance of the query

Comment: I know that this is a solution for a problem I am having but cannot dissect it to make it work for my purposes. I have a ticket explaining my issue, could I please get some help making this work for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948661/how-to-query-for-a-connected-journey-of-one-or-more-routes-train-travel Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 4):

Personally ... I would go with CTE in this example, but also this could be done with dynamic SQL, as you don't know how much stops some person is willing to go for, make a function and dynamic SQL will dot his for you and do as many joins as it's needed, now there could be more formatting and adding those arrows and stuff ... but seems it works like this

And you you can execute `@sql` into temporary table and have another where condition for stop `London`

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null drop table #Test
create table #Test ([From] nvarchar(20), [To] nvarchar(20))

insert into #Test ([From], [To])
values 
('Log Angeles', 'London'),
('Log Angeles', 'New York'),
('New York', 'London'),
('Log Angeles', 'Seattle'),
('Seattle', 'Paris'),
('Paris', 'London')

declare @StopsCount int = 2
declare @beginingStop int = 2

declare @sqlHeader nvarchar(max) = 'select t' + cast(@StopsCount as nvarchar) + 
                               '.[From], t' + + cast(@StopsCount as nvarchar) + 
                               '.[To] '

declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max) = 'from #Test t' + cast(@StopsCount as nvarchar)
while @StopsCount > 0
BEGIN

    set @StopsCount = @StopsCount - 1

    set @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' left join #Test t' + cast(@StopsCount as nvarchar) +
                  ' on t' + cast(convert(int, (@StopsCount + 1)) as nvarchar) + '.[To]' +
                  ' = t' + cast(@StopsCount as nvarchar) + '.[From]'                      
    set @sqlHeader = @sqlHeader + ', t' + cast(@StopsCount as nvarchar) + '.[To]'
END

set @sqlQuery = @sqlHeader + @sqlQuery + ' where t' 
+ cast(@beginingStop as nvarchar) + '.[From] = ''Log Angeles'''

execute (@sqlQuery)
```

Comment: This solution returns table with columns From, To, To, To - not what was asked in the task

Comment: Yep, that's why i said it 'now there could be more formatting and adding those arrows and stuff' ...

Comment: Please provide with [to City] Filter so we can search routes with FROM TO City.

Comment: @pratik1020 You should use answer above, and go with CTE, it is a lot easier to use it and apply wanted filter

Comment: OK, thanks it is working for me,But I want add cutoff time and delivery time with multiple route with Sunday,Monday,Th....etc...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for that good question.

This answer is not for specific RDBMS of OP (`not SQL Server`) but I write specific for `Oracle` that I'm familiar with.

The query uses Hierarchical Query instead of recursive CTE, with `LEVEL <= 3` equal to `TransfersCount <= 2` in SQL Server

```
WITH routes AS
(
    SELECT 'Los Angeles' from_place, 'London' to_place FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Los Angeles', 'New York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'New York', 'London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Los Angeles', 'Seattle' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Seattle', 'Paris' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Seattle', 'Los Angeles' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Paris', 'London' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(from_place , '->'), 3) || '->' || to_place AS path
FROM routes
WHERE to_place = 'London'
START WITH from_place = 'Los Angeles'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE  PRIOR to_place = from_place 
    AND to_place <> 'Los Angeles' 
    AND LEVEL <= 3 ;
```